# Why do I get an "Unresolved Externals" when calling a static attribute? Visual C++

Tags: c++, singleton, static-methods, static-variables, unresolved-external

although there are a lot of answers to this topic, I still have a problem.

I want, like everybody, to implement a Singleton pattern. I tried with this:

```
class Factory
{

private:
    Factory(void);
    static Factory* self_inst;

public:

    ~Factory(void);

    IPortIO* getStrategy(int portType);
    static Factory *getInstance()
    {           
        if(self_inst == NULL)
            self_inst = new Factory();
        return self_inst;       
    }

};
```

The problem comes when I call *self_inst* in the *getInstance()* static Method. A lot of people said that when using static variables, you must not only declare it, but define it somewhere else. Well, I've problem trying to define it in very place:

1 Outside the class:

```
Factory* Factory::self_inst;
```

2 Outside the class, with a value:

```
Factory* Factory::self_inst=NULL;
```

3 Inside the static method:

```
static Factory *getInstance()
{     
    Factory* Factory::self_inst;      
    if(self_inst == NULL)
        self_inst = new Factory();
    return self_inst;       
}
```

4 and inside the static method but with a value:

```
static Factory *getInstance()
{     
    Factory* Factory::self_inst=NULL;      
    if(self_inst == NULL)
        self_inst = new Factory();
    return self_inst;       
}
```

Nothing works! Finally I decided not to create a static attribute in the class, but a static variable inside the static method. This works, but it definitely not the same and also not a good programming practice, since what should I do if I need to access the same variable with two statics methods? It's not my case, but it's a good question and I would really like to know if someone knows hot to do it.

Comment: You should be able to define it in the .cpp which implements Factory functions. Do you get an error message when you put `Factory* Factory::self_inst = NULL;` in your .cpp file ?

Comment: Here is a [compileable](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7cef44ef9edf8b212f3ef17fcb4fba27-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59) example of your code. The static member should be initialized in your CPP file

Comment: Also, if you are using C++11, you should use `null_ptr` instead of the NULL macro.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 2 is right (actually so is number 1, because the default initialisation is to NULL), just remember to put it in a cpp file, not in the header.

If it's still not working post the error message.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The thing was to initialize the static variable in the CPP (not the header) file just as john and JBL said. Now it works properly.